# How to compute pairing in a smart contract

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, elliptic-curve

I am working on the elliptic curve and pairing stuff in Ethereum smart contract. How can I compute pairing such `e(p1,p2)`?

I know that we have a pre-compile pairing check in Ethereum client which is live at `0x08`, and performs the pairing *check*.

From the documentation:

```
success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 8, 0, add(input, 0x20), mul(inputSize, 0x20), out, 0x20)
```

This means we can just check equality of two pairings in a smart contract. However, I require the computation of exactly one pairing such as `e(p1,p2)=?` in Solidity.

Comment: Please try and be more concise, and try and avoid "as I see", "as I know" and especially "as I told" because you are not in the position to *tell* us anything. Please try and format your question to the best of your abilities, this was really all over the place.